# Altering behavior of Option + arrow keys in Numbers for Mac

Tags: keyboard, numbers, text-input

In Numbers, pressing <kbd>⌥ (option)</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (or with any other arrow key) will add a row or column in that direction, relative to the currently selected cell. This is a useful shortcut which I employ frequently, and I don’t want to turn it off.

However, I’m used to using that shortcut in text editing to quickly move the entry cursor around, by words rather than characters.

**What I would like is to have <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd> add new columns *except* when I’m editing a cell’s contents.**

I can simply reassign the keyboard shortcuts if necessary, but I’d like to know if what I ask is possible.